# Can I run multiprocessing with object class in python?

Tags: python, opencv, timer, multiprocessing, streaming

I wanna run a multiple object detection(YOLOv3) algorithm with different parameters.

I should use more CPU cores that by detecting and counting algorithms are too heavy to control.

So I made object class which can set different video names and GPU numbers but I am new about multiprocessing in python that I can't handle multiprocessing class well.

Features

```
1. Draw baselines in PySide2 or PyQt.
2. Select a GPU which will run the YOLOv3.
3. Count cars which crossed a specific line in a road.
```

But I wanna test if multiprocessing can run object class before really implementing.

```
# main.py
from stream import video
import multiprocessing as mp

print(mp.current_process())
process1 = mp.Process(target=video, args=('DJI_0474_2.MOV', 0))
process2 = mp.Process(target=video, args=('DJI_0474_3.MOV', 1))
process1.daemon = True
process2.daemon = True

process1.start()
process2.start()
```

```
# stream.py
import cv2
from threading import Timer
import multiprocessing as mp
# from yolov3 import YOLO

class video(object):
    def __init__(self, name, gpu_num):
        print(mp.current_process())
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(name)
        # self.detector = YOLO(gpu_num)

        self.timer = Timer(0.066, self.run)
        self.timer.start()

    def run(self):
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        if ret:
            # frame = self.detector(frame)
            cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
```

I made a simple code to test multiprocessing.

But when I initialize video class with two args('DJI_0474_2.MOV', 0), main.py closed itself.

I tried initializing before run multiprocessing but the error say "can't pickle cv2.VideoCapture objects".

```
# main2.py
from stream2 import video
import multiprocessing as mp

print(mp.current_process())
play = video('DJI_0474_2.MOV')
# process = mp.Process(target=video, args=('DJI_0474_2.MOV',))
process = mp.Process(target=play.run)
process.daemon = True
process.start()
```

```
# stream2.py
import cv2
from threading import Timer
import multiprocessing as mp
# from yolov3 import YOLO

class video(object):
    def __init__(self, name  ):
        print(mp.current_process())
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(name)

    def run(self):
        self.timer = Timer(0.066, self.update)
        self.timer.start()

    def update(self):
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        if ret:
            cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
               break
```

I think that's because 'video class' is on Main core but 'run' is on other core, so they can't communicate at the same time.

I will try queue to communicate between cores but I am worried about the latency... so the best is launching multiprocessing in the object class.

Is there any solution that I can run multiprocessing in object class?

Answer (score 0):

No ez way, what i can think is ros,boost, multithread and all kind of mutex. gonna take a while

The most stupid way is to build several yolo. say with gpu and various cpu version. 
Calling each 1 at different terminal to start new thread.

Then split the trained model for different subset by retraining N model. 
And each build version is calling a sub model

Then all finding findings to N txt file and then concatenated into one txt to avoide mutex lock issue.